# MVC POST Body to Object conversion is swallowing a thrown exception

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-apicontroller

I am trying to do some basic validation on my model classes.

In my project I have a model class:

```
public class SimpleRequest {
    string _message;
    string _otherProperty;

    public Message {
        get {return _message;}
        set {
            if (value=="THROW EXCEPTION")
                throw new Exception();
            _message = value;
        }
    }

    public OtherProperty {
        get {return _otherProperty;}
        set {
            _otherProperty= value;
        }
    }

}
```

In my ApiController I have a function

```
public string Post([FromBody] SimpleRequest) {
    // Something, it doesn't matter.
}
```

And in the Body

```
{
    "Message" : "THROW EXCEPTION",
    "OtherProperty" : "Hello World"
}
```

The issue is if the Post contains "THROW EXCEPTION" is does in fact throw it. But if you step through the code, after throwing the Exception the next step is the Post function. However, The SimpleRequest parameter is partially populated. Message is null, and OtherProperty is properly populated with "Hello World"

I would rather be able to capture the exception and return a result with a failure code. But at this point the exception just disappears.

Can I change this behavior? Or am I doing it wrong?

TIA!

Comment: Can you add your post payload?

Comment: because after throw exception control goes out of the set block without executing next statements

Comment: Why don't you just move the line: `_message = value;` to the start of the set{} block?

Comment: because then _message would be set to an invalid value. ("THROW EXCEPTION" is the invalid value in this small example.)

Answer (score 0):

Because when you throw exception next row is not called and that is why the _message is null.

Comment: What do you mean next row?

Comment: this row - _message = value;

Comment: Can I ask you what are you trying to achieve? It is very unusual to throw exception in model like this.

Comment: I am trying to keep invalid data out of my models. This seemed like a good solution.

Comment: well try to use ModelState instead and DataAnnotations.
https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/models-data/validation-with-the-data-annotation-validators-cs

or here is the link for WEB API
https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api